# Cannot read property 'id' of undefined when creating a todo in NewTodo.jsx

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to create a new todo and pass todo is creating id to redirect component but I've got following issue: "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined". This is NewTodo.jsx, when It's the error:

```
  class NewTodo extends Component {
    state = {
      redirect: false
    };

   componentDidMount() {
      this.props.newTodo();
     }

     submit = todo => {
           return this.props
            .saveTodo(todo)
            .then(response => this.setState({ redirect: true }))
            .catch(err => {
               throw new SubmissionError(this.props.errors);
           });
    };

      render() {
         return (
          <div>
           <h2>New Todo</h2>

            {this.state.redirect ? (
               <Redirect to={
     //ERROR            {pathname:`/todos/${this.props.location.state.id}/watch`,

    //ERROR             state: {id: this.props.todo._id}}
                }
               />
           ) : (
              <TodoForm todo={this.props.todo} onSubmit={this.submit} />
           )}
          </div>
        );
     }
   }

   function mapStateToProps(state) {
     return {
         todo: state.todosDs.todo,
         errors: state.todosDs.errors
     };
    }

  export default connect(
     mapStateToProps,
    { newTodo, saveTodo }
   )(NewTodo);
```

At lines when say ERROR it seems I'm passing an undefined id value. How can I access todo id I'm creating just the moment?

The expect result is '/todos/8eqwnhwebewj/watch' but real output is this following issue:

Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not wiring up the id with the correct object:

it should be it it a query param `this.props.location.search.id` not `this.props.location.state.id`

it should be it it a param eg `/path/:id` -> `this.props.location.match..id` not `this.props.location.state.id`

```
  <Redirect to={`/todos/${this.props.todo._id}/watch`}      }
  />
) : (
    <TodoForm todo={this.props.todo} onSubmit={this.submit} />
```

In your case you need to redirect to the path like this:

`/todos/${this.props.todo._id}/watch`

Comment: I did it as you said me, but I've got this issue: xhr.js:155 GET http://localhost:3000/api/todos/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Same Issue. Error must be in post route inside back end.

Answer (score 0):

if you using `react-router-dom` and this is not a component that renders directly in a route, try using `withRouter` to get the `history`, `location` and `match` as props in your component.

`withRouter` would provide `react-router-dom` props into your component.

api [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter)

Comment: I'm using react-router only

Comment: if its a web project you need to install `react-router-dom` and try `withRouter` way if doing it